# Joomla core table names for JTable::getInstance?

Tags: joomla-3.x, jtable

I'm building a tool to import content for various languages. It makes copies of existing items such as menus, articles, modules, etc. that have language specific content.

For example, when copying an article, I use the following to load the content table:

```
$contentSrcTbl = JTable::getInstance('Content', 'JTable', array());
$contentSrcTbl->load(array('alias' => $article['alias']));
```

I have the table names for menus, articles, and modules, but can't seem to find a list of tables names to use in the getInstance call. At the moment, I'm looking for the table name to use for template styles. I've tried:

- Template
- Templates
- Style
- Styles
- TemplateStyle
- TemplatesStyle
- TemplatesStyles
- TemplatesTableStyle

The last one is the name of the class in the tables folder under the Templates component.

But none of those return a jtable object, they all return null.

Is there a list showing the table names associated with the core Joomla tables?

If no list, how can I find out what to use for the table name?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Class name is `TemplatesTableStyle`. But since it's not a core class, you have to register it:

```
JLoader::register('TemplatesTableStyle', JPATH_ADMINISTRATOR . '/components/com_templates/tables/style.php');
```

or include the whole com_templates/tables folder:

```
JTable::addIncludePath(JPATH_ADMINISTRATOR . '/components/com_templates/tables');
```

Then this should work:

```
$table = JTable::getInstance('Style', 'TemplatesTable', array());
```

Comment: What about the other "core" components, IOW, components included with a Joomla install?

Comment: Same, if table files are in component directory. Here's a list of core tables that don't need to be registered https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/tree/aba23aa72545de7323c57c4206f22e5e89758e96/libraries/src/Table